# XPath predicate with sub-paths with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to understand and XPath that was sent to me for use with ACORD XML forms (common format in insurance).  The XPath they sent me is (truncated for brevity):

```
./PersApplicationInfo/InsuredOrPrincipal[InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]/GeneralPartyInfo
```

Where I'm running into trouble is that Python's [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de/) is telling me that `[InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]` is an `invalid predicate`.  I'm not able to find anywhere in the [XPath spec on predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Predicate) which identifies this syntax so that I can modify this predicate to work.

Is there any documentation on what exactly this predicate is selecting?  Also, is this even a valid predicate, or has something been mangled somewhere?

**Possibly related:**

I believe the company I am working with is an MS shop, so this XPath may be valid in C# or some other language in that stack?  I'm not entirely sure.

**Updates:**

Per comment demand, here is some additional info.

XML sample:

```
<ACORD>
  <InsuranceSvcRq>
    <HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
      <PersPolicy>
        <PersApplicationInfo>
            <InsuredOrPrincipal>
                <InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
                    <InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>AN</InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>
                </InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
                <GeneralPartyInfo>
                    <Addr>
                        <Addr1></Addr1>
                    </Addr>
                </GeneralPartyInfo>
            </InsuredOrPrincipal>
        </PersApplicationInfo>
      </PersPolicy>
    </HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
  </InsuranceSvcRq>
</ACORD>
```

Code sample (with full XPath instead of snippet):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(raw)
>>> tree.find('./InsuranceSvcRq/HomePolicyQuoteInqRq/PersPolicy/PersApplicationInfo/InsuredOrPrincipal[InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]/GeneralPartyInfo/Addr/Addr1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1409, in lxml.etree._Element.find (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:39972)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 271, in find
    it = iterfind(elem, path, namespaces)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 261, in iterfind
    selector = _build_path_iterator(path, namespaces)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 245, in _build_path_iterator
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](_next, token))
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.5-macosx-10.3-i386.egg/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 207, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Comment: Would you post an example of the XML that `InsuredOrPrincipal[InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]` is supposed to match?

Comment: Actually, the XPath spec does say that predicates can contain path expressions, but the reference is pretty obscure: `PredicateExpr ::= '[' Expr ']'`, where `Expr` can contain arbitrary relational expressions, including `PathExpr`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change `tree.find` to `tree.xpath`. `find` and `findall` are present in lxml to provide compatibility with other implementations of ElementTree. [These methods do not implement the entire XPath language](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#what-are-the-findall-and-xpath-methods-on-element-tree). To employ XPath expressions containing more advanced features, use the `xpath` method, the `XPath` class, or `XPathEvaluator`.

For example:

```
import io
import lxml.etree as ET

content='''\
<ACORD>
  <InsuranceSvcRq>
    <HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
      <PersPolicy>
        <PersApplicationInfo>
            <InsuredOrPrincipal>
                <InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
                    <InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>AN</InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>
                </InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
                <GeneralPartyInfo>
                    <Addr>
                        <Addr1></Addr1>
                    </Addr>
                </GeneralPartyInfo>
            </InsuredOrPrincipal>
        </PersApplicationInfo>
      </PersPolicy>
    </HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
  </InsuranceSvcRq>
</ACORD>
'''
tree=ET.parse(io.BytesIO(content))
path='//PersApplicationInfo/InsuredOrPrincipal[InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]/GeneralPartyInfo'
result=tree.xpath(path)
print(result)
```

yields

```
[<Element GeneralPartyInfo at b75a8194>]
```

while `tree.find` yields

```
SyntaxError: invalid node predicate
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example is perfectly fine in my opinion. I would check if lxmls XPath implementation has some documented limitations or something like that.

Comment: From my understanding lxml is basically an interface to libxml2, and I cannot find any information on either of these not having a full implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
./PersApplicationInfo/InsuredOrPrincipal
                 [InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]
                     /GeneralPartyInfo/
```

**A few problems with this expression**:

1. **The ending `/` character makes it syntactically invalid**. It marks the start of a new location step, but nothing follows.
2. As Dr. Michael Kay noticed, you may have problems with nested quotes in Python.

**Suggested solution**:

```
./PersApplicationInfo/InsuredOrPrincipal
                 [InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd='AN']
                     /GeneralPartyInfo
```

In this expression double quotes are replaced with single quotes. The second change is the removal of the ending `/` character.

**Update**: Now the OP has provided a more complete code sample, I am able to verify that there is nothing wrong with the actual XPath expression used. Below is its verification with XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  './InsuranceSvcRq/HomePolicyQuoteInqRq/PersPolicy
                 /PersApplicationInfo/InsuredOrPrincipal
                     [InsuredOrPrincipalInfo/InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd="AN"]
                                                   /GeneralPartyInfo/Addr/Addr1'/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this tranformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ACORD>
    <InsuranceSvcRq>
        <HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
            <PersPolicy>
                <PersApplicationInfo>
                    <InsuredOrPrincipal>
                        <InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
                            <InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>AN</InsuredOrPrincipalRoleCd>
                        </InsuredOrPrincipalInfo>
                        <GeneralPartyInfo>
                            <Addr>
                                <Addr1></Addr1>
                            </Addr>
                        </GeneralPartyInfo>
                    </InsuredOrPrincipal>
                </PersApplicationInfo>
            </PersPolicy>
        </HomePolicyQuoteInqRq>
    </InsuranceSvcRq>
</ACORD>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Addr1 />
```

**Conclusion**: The problem is either in the Python code use, or (less-likely) the used XPath engine has a bug.

Comment: I had been trimming the trailing `/` off of the XPaths before use, because it caused incorrect nodes to be returned.  I just forgot to remove it when I copy/pasta'd it here.  I am also enclosing the string in single quotes, though I tried it both ways to be thorough.  Still throws a `SyntaxError` with `invalid predicate`.  Is there any documentation on this type of predicate in the spec?

Comment: @Jack M. In case you provide the full XPath expression and the code in which it participates, then many people will point out to you the exact reason for the issue. As everyone pointed out, the fragment of the XPath expression that you provide in your questin, is correct -- therefore the problem is in the code that you haven't shown to us.

Comment: @Jack M. : I have updated my answer with verification (in XSLT) that the XPath expression is correct and that this XPath expression selects the node it is intended to.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath you were given is perfectly correct. Perhaps the problem arose with embedding it in Python, where you will need to use Python escape conventions to escape the double-quotes in a character string?

Comment: The string was within single quotes, so no escaping is necessary.