# Parse xml node children list by tag with any prefix in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, domparser

I would like to got an list of items, independently of their prefixes.
My goal is to create method (please notice me if something like this exist), who has one argument(tagname) and returns list of elements.

For example in case of argument 'item' `<media:item>`, `<abc:item>` should be part of result of this function.

It would be nice to use lxml but it can be any python DOM-based parser.

Unfortunatuly i can't assume, that xml has xmlns, that's why i need to parse for any prefix.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302594/wildcard-namespaces-in-lxml

Comment: what do you mean by *"i can't assume, that xml has xmlns"*. Does it mean, for example, `media` prefix may never been declared anywhere (there is no `xmlns:media="..."` anywhere in the XML document)?

Comment: @har07
Yes, often xml creators forgot about xmlns declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lxml` is a good option primarily because it has full support for XPath version 1.0 via the `xpath()` method besides many other useful utilities. And in XPath, you can ignore element namespace by using `local-name()` as mentioned in the comment.

`lxml` also able to deal with undefined prefix by setting parameter `recover=True`, but now comes the catch; `local-name()` still return prefixed 'tagname' for element having undefined prefix. There is a hacky way to match this kind of element, by finding element which local name *contains* `:tagname` -or to be more precise, find element which local name [`ends with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437888/2998271) `:tagname` instead of *contains*-.

The following is a working example for demo. The demo uses two expressions combined with logical operator `or`; one for dealing with element having undefined prefix, and the other for element without prefix or with properly defined prefix :

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """<root foo="bar">
    <media:item>a</media:item>
    <abc:item>b</abc:item>
    <foo:item>c</foo:item>
    <item>d</item>
</root>"""
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)
tagname = "item"
#expression to match element undefined prefix
predicate1 = "contains(local-name(),':{0}')".format(tagname)
#expression to match element with properly defined prefix or with no prefix
predicate2 = "local-name()='{0}'".format(tagname)
elements = tree.xpath("//*[{0} or {1}]".format(predicate1, predicate2))
for e in elements:
    print(etree.tostring(e))
```

**output :**

```
<media:item>a</media:item>

<abc:item>b</abc:item>

<foo:item>c</foo:item>

<item>d</item>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what i need :) I have never used xpath before.